# Uno Platform - xamarin No Virtual method getTargetState()

Tags: xamarin.android, uno-platform

I recently updated Visual Studio 2019 to 16.9.  When it updated- there was a message indicating that the Android SDK was updated.  When I go to run the IOS version of my Uno Project- it runs fine.  However- when I go to run it on the Android version- I have had a few issues.  At first it would not compile- but after doing some web searches I found I needed to reenable AAPT.  I am now able to compile it- but I get an exception when I run the app on my android device.  It says no virtual method getTargetState()- and then lists the library as the picture shows.   I checked Nuget for any package updates and applied them- but still have the same error.  It is showing a method missing- that presumably was there earlier.  I am not sure how to resolve this- so any help would be appreciated.

[image: Error seen when trying]

Comment: Whether to try to update the related NuGet package ？

Comment: I did try updating the package- it did not have an update available.

Answer (score 0):

I started thinking about what Leo Zhu said above and it made me think- there was no update to the package mentioned.  Maybe there was a breaking change in the package that was installed?  So- I downgraded it to 2.2.0.3- and it is working again.  One point to make is I was using the latest alpha release- so a breaking change is not surprising.  I hope this helps someone else that encounters this issue or a similar issue.